# Any way to know if form POST destination generates an error

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a webform that gets submitted to an endpoint/URL that I cannot access, to make any changes.

I would like to know if there is any way to listen for or capture errors that could come from the POST URL. An example would be if the URL is no longer valid, or there is a network issue, so it takes a long time or times out.

So specifically, once the form is submitted, is there any way in Javascript, on the client, to listen for or be aware of any errors due to issues with the server side URL the form is posting to. And to clarify, the form is submitted as a standard web form, not using Ajax or any newer JS implementation.

Thanks

Comment: How are you submitting your form now?  Are you using AJAX or are you using the `<form>` element?

Comment: Depends on how the backend is handling errors, if the backend doesn't send back a status code error or some type of exception message, not much you can do about it on the front end.

Comment: If you're submitting a normal web form, I don't think there's anything you can do, the browser handles it all internally. If you want more control, you have to use AJAX to submit it from Javascript.

Comment: I am just using a normal form, with POST action, no Ajax involved. I do not think this is possible, but always like to see about second (or third opinions) before I say "It can't be done".